# Intel Xeon X3430 for Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v

I'm looking for a compute to run Hyper-V. Does an Intel Xeon X3430, 4C, 2 meet Hyper-V hardware-requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://ark.intel.com/products/42927/Intel-Xeon-Processor-X3430-8M-Cache-2_40-GHz

```
Advanced Technologies
Intel® Turbo Boost Technology   Yes
Intel® vPro Technology  No
Intel® Hyper-Threading Technology   No
Intel® Virtualization Technology (VT-x) Yes
Intel® Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O (VT-d)    Yes
Intel® Trusted Execution Technology Yes
```

So, you've got 4 cores, 8M cache, and VT-x and VT-d.  No Hyperthreading, so you only get 4 cores and 4 threads.

Yes, It's fine for Hyper-v, if a little limited on threads.